# Method that returns the average of all the words in an array

Tags: java

Basically, I'm trying to make a method that counts all the letters in the array and return  the sum divided by the count which im doing terribly bad. And I'm stuck. what I have is even to embarrassing to put up.

Comment: Could you please post what you've attempted anyway? At this point your question looks no different from a homework dump.

Comment: There is nothing such as embarrassing here. We understand you are learning, so just post what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure I understand what you want, but this could be it:

```
float averageWordLength(String[] words)
{
    int len;
    for(String s : words) {
        len += s.length();
    }
    return len / (float)words.length;
}
```

You can use `double` instead of `float` if you want more accuracy, or just `int` if you want it floored...

Comment: `float` rather than `double`?

Comment: will it make a difference?

Comment: Depends, `float` is a 32bit floating point and `double` is 64bit - the double has more precision. On a 64bit system there's not really a reason to use a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of words:

```
final String[] words = {
        "an",
        "array",
        "of",
        "words"};
```

With Java 8 you can do:

```
final IntSummaryStatistics statistics = Arrays.stream(words)
        .mapToInt(String::length)
        .summaryStatistics();
```

From [IntSummaryStatistics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) you can query the average:

```
final double average = statistics.getAverage();
```